# Using SQL Will Fix Concurrency Issues?

Tags: sql, linq, concurrency

I am developing a set of applications that all hit the same database, and concurrency has been one of the biggest issues I've had to deal with.

I'm developing solutions to work around these issues, and I recently thought of using SQL queries instead of LINQ queries to update databases.  Because SQL has pessimistic concurrency control, in terms of preventing concurrency issues, is this a good and simple solution to my LINQ concurrency woes?

Comment: You are wrong - SQL typically also uses optimistic concurrency modes, so switching to "pure" SQL from Linq doesn't get you any benefits at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq just passes SQL statements to SQL Server. So it could very well be sending SQL Server the same statements you would be generating. And besides, SQL Server uses optimistic concurrency. So I think you have other issues.

Comment: @marc_s - Using SQL or Linq wouldn't make any difference, IMO.